# SwiftDate 5.0 compilation issues

Tags: ios, swift, swiftdate

When I install SwiftDate through Cocoapods and try to build my project, I get three errors from the SwiftDate library:

> /Pods/SwiftDate/Sources/SwiftDate/DateInRegion/DateInRegion.swift:11:15:
>   Type 'DateInRegion' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
>
> /Pods/SwiftDate/Sources/SwiftDate/DateInRegion/DateInRegion+Create.swift:50:33:
>   Type 'UInt32' has no member 'random'
>
> /Pods/SwiftDate/Sources/SwiftDate/DateInRegion/DateInRegion+Create.swift:65:37:
>   Type 'UInt32' has no member 'random'

Am I using an incorrect version of SwiftDate, Swift, or XCode? When I try to install SwiftDate 4.5.1, I get no errors in the library but none of the SwiftDate functions actually work.

Comment: What versions of XCode and Swift are you using?

Comment: @user28434 XCode 9.4 and Swift 4.1. I installed SwiftDate 4.5 as Robert Dresler suggested, but as far as I can tell none of the functions work correctly. I feel like I am importing the wrong thing to my file... I can't find what I am supposed to import in the installation guide though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since versions **5.0.0+** of *SwiftDate* include code from *Swift* **4.2**, you have to have installed Xcode which supports this version of Swift (Xcode 10+).

Otherwise you can use the latest version of *SwiftDate* which doesn't use code from Swift 4.2 such as getting random number easily (SwiftDate 4.5.0) by specifing the version of cocoapod in podfile

```
pod 'SwiftDate', '4.5.0'
```

Comment: Ok so I had done that before but none of the functions listed in the documentation worked. It just says they are unrecognized functions so I assumed that it did not install correctly. Is there separate documentation for SwiftDates 4.5?

for example: `let date1 = DateInRegion("2016-01-05", format: "yyyy-MM-dd", region: regionNY)`

returns: `Use of unresolved identifier 'DateInRegion'` and `Use of unresolved identifier 'regionNY'`

Comment: @NolanGelinas https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate/releases/tag/5.0.0 maybe you will find their first version for Swift 4.2+ changes usefull. They describe what’s changed from previous versions. Anyway, if you don’t have any specific reasons, I would suggest you to update your Xcode to version which supports Swift 4.2+ (means Xcode 10+)

Comment: Yeah I would love to update to XCode 4.2 but unfortunately I am writing my app on a school laptop running High Sierra 10.13.5, and XCode 10+ requires High Sierra 10.13.6... They will most certainly not update my Os so I am stuck with XCode 9.4 til next year I guess. Thanks for all the help though :) (also I figured out that `regionNY` was an example variable, not a class. My bad.)

Comment: @NolanGelinas ok, so is everything alright now? I’m glad! Good luck mate! ;)

Answer (score 0):

As per SwiftDate [release notes](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate/releases) the latest version is using Swift 4.2 (starting from 5.0.9) so I assume that you are using an older version of Swift.

Otherwise check the migration guide for more informations.
https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate/blob/master/Documentation/10.Upgrading_SwiftDate4.md